# PostgreSQL Window Functions Ignore Null Values

Tags: postgresql, lag

I am relatively new to PostgreSQL and am having a difficult time trying to implement the lag() function while ignoring null values.  According to the docs, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html, it is not possible to simply pass a parameter to the function to achieve this.

Does anyone know of any workaround?  You can make up any example but if it helps here is something to get you started:

```
Col_A   Col_B  Col_A_Lag  Col_B_Lag  ID  Date
VA_1    100    VA_1       100        AA  Jan-1 
null    null   VA_1       100        AA  Jan-2
null    null   VA_1       100        AA  Jan-3
VA_2    250    VA_2       250        AA  Jan-4
VA_2    300    VA_2       300        AA  Jan-5  
null    null   VA_2       300        AA  Jan-6
```

If I am pulling from tbl_x, here is a simple SQL script:

```
select
Col_A,
Col_B,
case when Col_A is null then lag(Col_A) over w else Col_A end as Col_A_Lag,
case when Col_B is null then lag(Col_B) over w else Col_B end as Col_B_Lag
from tbl_x
window w as (partition by ID order by Date)
```

This script will *not* return what I want because it includes the null values when it 'looks back' in the lag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you can't just:

```
select
from tbl_x
window w as (partition by ID order by Date)
where col_a is null;
```

If not then you might have to:

```
select
Col_A,
Col_B,
case when Col_A is null
  then (select col_a
          from tbl_x x2
         where x2.id = x1.id
           and col_a is not null
           and x2.date < x1.date
      order by date desc
         limit 1)
  else Col_A
  end Col_A_Lag,
case when Col_B is null
  then (select col_b
          from tbl_x x2
         where x2.id = x1.id
           and col_b is not null
           and x2.date < x1.date
      order by date desc
         limit 1)
  else Col_B
  end Col_B_Lag
from tbl_x x1;
```

With appropriate indexing the performance would probably be pretty good.

```
create index ... (id, date desc, col_b) where col_b is not null;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but your second solution does not work when Col_A changes.  I either get all VA_1 values or VA_2 values in Col_A_Lag depending on how I sort 'date'.

Comment: Ah didn't spot that bit of logic. Edited the query to include it.

Comment: Closer... all null values are filled in with VA_1.... the last should be VA_2.  Thanks.